# Spring MVC - accessing objects from a list in JSP for a form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a form with multiple objects being passed.
I am trying to create a form where you can find '`product`' and '`customer`' and add them to order.
I have 2 model classes `Customer` and `Product`. `Customer` has `phoneNo` variable, `Product` has `name` variable.
I found that easiest way to pass multiple objects is to add them to list and pass `List` to a `View`. That's what I'm doing, but accessing those model objects is a different story.

**Controller class:**

```
 @Controller
    public class OrderController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/create_order", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView create_order() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("customer", new Customer());
        model.put("product", new Product());


        return new ModelAndView("create_order", "command", model);
    }
    }
```

**Page:**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/Persistence_Web/order_confirmation" commandName="model">
<table>
<!-- I tried few different ways of writing it and all fail -->
    <tr><form:label path="model[0].phoneNo">Customer phone number</form:label></tr>
    <tr><form:input path="model[0].phoneNo"></form:input></tr>
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer the attributes `Product.name` and `Customer.phoneNo` in your model, you have to refer the names you give in the model plus the attribute name (**that must have a getter in the class!!!**)

```
<tr><form:input path="${customer.phoneNo}"></form:input></tr>
<tr><form:input path="${product.name}"></form:input></tr>
```

*The attributes in the classes MUST have getters and setters if you want to manipulate them in the view. The naming must be:

```
private int attributeName
public  int getAttributeName()
```

**BUT**: as long as the getter method in the class is like your *variable name* in the view. You can have a `getMyCalculation()` method **WITHOUT** `myCalculation` attribute in order to calculate totals, averages, formatting dates, or whatever you need to show in the view but not store in the model.

Also, for various `Products` or `Customers` use a list:

```
List<Customer> customers = // fill the list!!!
model.put("customers", customers);
```

And iterate with a `<for:earch>`

```
<c:forEach items="${customers}" var="customer">     
    <c:out value="${customer.phoneNo}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yup thank you, it worked. On example i did with single object path was defined with single string like path="variable", so that got me confused.
And for getter - of course it does, but does it matter if it has default naming like "getVariableName()", or can getter have any name as long as it returns variable needed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood your question you can't access model object in this way. Please try using spring placeholders `${command.get('customer').phoneNo}`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I haven't noticed that model object are used in the `path` attr.
I meant that to access model's object you have to use plaseholders, and in this way you should specify something like that: `${command.get("customer")}`